# How to manage Flutter dependencies' dependencies?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I was building my Flutter app and I encountered the following error:

`R8: Program type already present: com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.OpenCameraInterface`

I believe this occurs because I am using both `flutter_qr_reader` and `qr_code_scanner` and they have their own QR code Scanners using the device's camera. I am using `qr_code_scanner` for scanning QR codes using the device's camera (I like the UI more) while I am using `flutter_qr_reader` to scan a QR code by importing a photo of it.

Is there any way to manage the dependencies without removing one package for the other?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding a dependency_overrides on the pubspec.yaml